# What is causing dispatchGesture to fail?

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility, android-service, gesture

I have an accessibility service defined as:

```kotlin
class ClickService : AccessibilityService() {
    // Pretend the necessary methods are overrided

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val binding = TODO() // Pretend we have a view binding here
        binding.clickButton.setOnClickListener {
            click(100, 200)
        }
    }

    private fun click(x: Int, y: Int) {
        val gesture = GestureDescription.Builder().addStroke(
            GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(
                Path().apply { moveTo(x.toFloat(), y.toFloat()) },
                0, // startTime
                1, // duration
            )
        )
        dispatchGesture(gesture.build(), null, null)
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<service
    android:name=".ui.ClickService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
    android:canPerformGestures="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

`ClickService` is then started as a foreground service from my `MainActivity`.

Running this (and giving the app its accessibility permissions) makes `dispatchGesture` return true, but it never simulates its click.  Why is that? What's making this silently fail?

My thoughts on why this didn't work were:

1. Perhaps there were additional permissions required that I was missing.
2. Maybe `dispatchGesture` was running outside of the UI thread.

However:

1. I already have `canPerformGestures` set to `true` in the service's manifest. Other than enabling accessibility for the app (which already have), I don't see any other required permissions.
2. I've looked into this, and it seems like `setOnClickListener`'s callback is already run in the UI thread, so I shouldn't need to do anything special to make `dispatchGesture` run from the same thread.

Why does `dispatchGesture` return true, but then doesn't actually click on anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be simple. For me, I wasn't defining the `AndroidManifest` properly.
`android:canPerformGestures` was set to true, but not where android reads it from.

Here is the updated service in `AndroidManifest.xml` (notice the meta-data element):

```xml
<service
    android:name=".ui.ClickService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
        android:resource="@xml/config_accessibility_service" />
</service>
```

Create a file in `res/xml/config_accessibility_service.xml` (or whatever you want to name it, but make sure it matches in your `AndroidManifest`:

```xml
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:canPerformGestures="true" />
```